# Spatial Data Type

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I think i can´t find my (obvious stupid) error :-).

Following SELECT statement on the database:

```
SELECT geography::STMPolyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON( (((11.791039 47.5448077, 11.7910551 47.544757, 11.7911677 47.5446375, 11.7644687 47.542786))) )',4326)
```

And the error is:

```
NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 26 of the input. The input has (11.791039.
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeDouble()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseLineStringText()
```

Can´t find my mistake, maybe one of you see the error ?!

---

Just found the solution: a '(' was too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have one too many pairs of parenthesis after `MULTIPOLYGON`... [this example shows only 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933816.aspx), but you have 4.

Instead, try:

```
SELECT geography::STMPolyFromText
(
    'MULTIPOLYGON
    ( 
        (
            (
                11.791039 47.5448077, 
                11.7910551 47.544757, 
                11.7911677 47.5446375, 
                11.7644687 47.542786
            )
        ) 
    )',4326
)
```